# AdobeImageIntent error

Tags: android, adobe, adobecreativesdk

I have been trying to integrate the Adobe Creative SDK in my app. I have added one extra activity which launches camera and gallery and saves the image in an ImageView.

I successfully passed the image to another activity but for using the Adobe Creative SDK you need an uri path.

After providing the uri path I am getting an error - 
'AdobeImageIntent()' has private access in 'com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageIntent'

here is the onCreate method -

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imageBitmap");
        String path = bmp.toString();

        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent().Builder(this)
                .setData(imageUri)
                .withOutput(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "my-pic-name.jpg")) // output file destination
                .withOutputFormaat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                .withOutputSize(MegaPixels.Mp5)
                .withOutputQuality(90)
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent,1);

        Intent cdsIntent = AdobeImageIntent.createCdsInitIntent(getBaseContext(),"CDS");
        startService(cdsIntent);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);



    }
```

why I am getting this error?

Thanks for help!
 Hope I would get answers!!

Comment: Can you let us know what version of the Creative SDK you are using? Also, you might have a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/tree/master/image-editor-ui) to see a basic example of using the Image Editor in an app.

Comment: It's 0.9.7 version...we actually wanted to take pictures from camera and passing on to editor

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent().Builder(this)
                                              ^^^^^
```

with:

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
                                             ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

## Possible issues with the code above

Try removing the `cdsIntent` and see if your code runs.

Without more information, it's hard to know, but it could be that both your `cdsIntent` and your `imageView` assignments are coming too late in `onCreate()`.

## Taking a photo from your app

You can create a new camera Intent and start it like this:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 400); // Can be any int
}
```

The results from the camera will come back to you in `onActivityResult()`.

## Handling the results from the camera Intent

How to handle the results will depend on what your app does. Google has a nice overview on the subject on the [Android Developer Portal](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

---

If you have further questions beyond the scope of this one, it may be good to make a new question to help get this one more focused.

Comment: For understanding how to use the Image Editor itself, I highly recommend trying the [GitHub repo that I posted](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/tree/master/image-editor-ui) in the comments on your question.